# In Django Rest Framework, how do handle invalid filtering parameters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to limit the queryset returned by a `ListAPIView`, using the filtering technique described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).

The question is, how do I handle invalid parameters?  Raising a ValidationError only works for serializers, not within the ViewSet.  I'd like to let the user know that the request was invalid, rather than failing silently.

For example:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
              try:
                  user = User.objects.get(username=username)
              except User.DoesNotExist:
                  # How do I handle this invalid parameter?
              else:
                  queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser=user)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the build in exceptions, since you are responding for something that was not found, use the NotFound:

```
from rest_framework import exceptions

class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
              try:
                  user = User.objects.get(username=username)
              except User.DoesNotExist:
                  raise exceptions.NotFound(detail="Some message if you want")
              else:
                  return queryset.filter(purchaser=user)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just return an empty list?

```
queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
```

If it is an invalid username this queryset will just be an empty queryset and DRF will return an empty list in result.

Comment: This question is about letting the user know that the request was invalid, rather than failing silently.